# Conditionally select column and group results on a series of partially duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I've been reading how to solve this issue, but since i lack the knowledge to either build this query correctly or even searching for the correct answer i'll have to ask here and hope you can help me out.

Assuming i have a table named `VENDORS`like this:

```
ID|name   |phone   |phone_type
 1| Andy  |305332  |office   
 1| Andy  |999999  |fax    
 1| Andy  |555555  |cellphone       
 2| Jack  |222222  |office       
 2| Jack  |444444  |fax     
 3| Peter |234234  |office       
 3| Peter |434345  |cellphone
```

How do i build a query so i get this:

```
ID|name   |phone   |fax      |cellphone
 1| Andy  |305332  |999999   |555555
 2| Jack  |222222  |444444   |NULL       
 3| Peter |234234  |NULL     |434345
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN phone_type = 'office' 
            THEN phone END AS phone
        WHEN phone_type = 'fax' 
            THEN phone END AS fax,
        WHEN phone_type = 'cellphone' 
            THEN phone END AS cellphone  
FROM `VENDORS`
GROUP BY id
```

But of course this is not working, not sure how to get what i want, it seems easy, but i'm totally lost.

Comment: My bad, syntax error in one hand, when using multiple cases, if using just one or the `IF` syntax, the grouped results only have one phone type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working solution with subqueries:

```
SELECT id, name,
    (SELECT phone FROM vendors WHERE id = v.id AND phone_type = 'office') as office,
    (SELECT phone FROM vendors WHERE id = v.id AND phone_type = 'fax') as fax,
    (SELECT phone FROM vendors WHERE id = v.id AND phone_type = 'cellphone') as cellphone
FROM vendors v 
GROUP BY id
```

A working fiddle you can find here:
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42b355/2

Comment: Indeed it works, i might be concerned about speed (or not?), but works perfectly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name, 
    CASE WHEN phone_type = 'office' 
            THEN phone 
            ELSE NULL END AS office,
    CASE WHEN phone_type = 'fax' 
            THEN phone 
            ELSE NULL END AS fax,
    CASE WHEN phone_type = 'cellphone' 
            THEN phone 
            ELSE NULL END AS cellphone  
FROM `VENDORS`
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I got a syntax error, `near 'WHEN phone_type = 'fax' THEN phone ELSE NULL END AS fa' at line 8`

Comment: No syntax error now, but its not getting the results properly, it only sets one of the phone types with valid data, the rest gets null.